# Proper Shortcode Usage in Template File

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a two part shortcode, with opening and closing shortcodes, in a template file.  See example below.

```
echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode][/myshortcode]');
```

I see from the Codex that I can do this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode]' . '<div class="anyHTML">Any Text</div>' . '[/myshortcode]');
```

Is it possible/correct or will it work to do this instead?

```
echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode]');
    $somePHP = possibleWordPressLoopCodeOrOtherPHP;
echo do_shortcode('[/myshortcode]');
```

I'm wondering about this to see if I can include PHP inside a two part shortcode, possibly a WordPress loop for a CPT or even other PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the whole shortcode block inside the `do_shortcode` function. So you could do something like this:

```
$text = some_code_or_function_that_returns_text_your_shortcode_can_act_on();
$sc_string = sprintf("[myshortcode]\n%s\n[/myshortcode]", $text);
echo do_shortcode($sc_string);
```

Comment: Can you clarify for me what `\n%s\n` is?  Your answer looks like it will work for me.

Comment: In php strings, `\n` is a newline character, like pressing enter in an editor. In `sprintf`, `%s` is a placeholder to be replaced by a string value. In this case, `%s` will be replaced with the contents of `$text`. See [the sprintf documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).